# Stretch Video Content To Full Screen Parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

**PREAMBLE**

I have embedded a MPVideoPlayerController within a full screen view at the back of a view controller.

In front of said video are functional buttons.

**PROBLEM**

The actual video content is limited to the centre parameters of the view with huge black border at either end [ top / bottom ]

**QUESTION**

How do I manipulate the actual video content size to consume the entire view / screen ?

**CODE**

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MenuViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *mediaContent;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mediaContainer;

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

// Background media.
- (void) executeMedia
{
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"static" ofType:@"mp4"];

    NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath];

    self.mediaContent = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: mediaURL];

    self.mediaContent.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    self.mediaContent.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    [self.mediaContent prepareToPlay];

    [self.mediaContent.view setFrame:self.mediaContainer.bounds];

    [self.mediaContainer addSubview:self.mediaContent.view];

    [self.mediaContent play];
}

@end
```

Comment: Solution: [self.mediaContent setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];